# Как сделать такой шаблон?

Tags: html, css

Шаблон должен быть только на `html4` и `css2`.

[image]

Comment: не работает background:url(../../images/bg_bottom.png) left bottom repeat-x #ffffff;

Comment: Уберите #ffffff;